# multi insert in kohana orm3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

In my application i have a loop that executes about 1000 times, inside it i'm creating object and saving it. This is the part of application where i populate my database with data. In common this looks like this:

```
foreach(...){
    ...
    try{
        $object = new Model_Whatever;
        $object->whatever=$whatever;
        $object->save();}
    catch(Exception $e){
    ...}
}
                    }
```

This produces 1000 of INSERT queries. Is it possible to, in some way, made kohana produce multi inserts. Split this into 10 inserts with 100 data sets in each. Is it possible and if yes that what is the way doing so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whilst the Kohana ORM doesn't support multi inserts, you can still use the query builder as follows:

```
$query = DB::insert('tablename', array('column1', 'column2','column3'));
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $query->values($d);
}
try {
    $result = $query->execute();
} catch ( Database_Exception $e ) {   
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

- you'll still need to split the data up so the above doesn't try to execute a query with 1000 inserts.
- $data assumes an array of arrays with the values corresponding to the order of the columns

thanks Isaiah in #kohana

Comment: Also the question is how to implement "insert ignore"? While adding 100 records, one of them may already exist in database and if so, adding of all 100 records will be declined.

Answer (score 0):

php work very slow when insert multi array very big (so that method ::values have array_merge) so more fast:

```
class Database_Query_Builder_Bath_Insert 
    extends Database_Query_Builder_Insert{

    public static function doExecute($table, $data) {
        $insertQuery = DB::insert($table, array_keys(current($data)));

        $insertQuery->_values = $data;

        $insertQuery->execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func_array([$query, 'values'], $data);
```