# kohana bulk insert

Tags: kohana, kohana-orm

is there a way to add multiple records at a time. usually we call it bulk insert.
currently i doing the following:

```
 foreach ($datalist as $data)
        try {

                    $this->template_id = $data['template_id'];
                    $this->notifier_id = $data['notifier_id'];
                    $this->user_id = $data['user_id'];
                    $this->date_created= date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
                    $this->save();
                    return true;
                } catch (Kohana_Exception $e) {
                    return false;
                }
    }
```

Comment: i dun want to run insert in loop

Comment: Are you using kohana orm module?

Comment: possible duplicate of [multi insert in kohana orm3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002714/multi-insert-in-kohana-orm3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$query = DB::insert('company_schedule', array('day', 'work_start', 'work_end', 'week_start', 'week_end', 'company_id')); // create sql request
$query->values(array(
                    $key, $work_start, $work_end, $week_start, $week_end, $this->id
                )); // do it in loop
$query->execute(); // execute
```